# Not Able to create and drop sequence in an anonymous block in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Today I have tried to create a sequence inside anonymous block. My requirement is when sequence is reached the maxvalue then it should be dropped automatically. So, I have executed the below code but it shows error like "PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist".

```
CODE:

DECLARE
V_NUM NUMBER:=0;
V_QUERY VARCHAR2(2000);
CNT NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
V_QUERY:= 'CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 10 MAXVALUE 200';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY;

FOR I IN 1..11 LOOP
SELECT SEQ_GEN.NEXTVAL INTO V_NUM FROM DUAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_NUM);
IF V_NUM >= 200 THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sequence has reached maximum value');
END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT FROM USER_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'SEQ_GEN';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CNT);

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Can anyone assist me to solve this issue?

Comment: Line 7 tries to drop the sequence before it is created on line 8.  To help debug this, remove the exception block.  By default, Oracle would stop execution and print the error and the line number, which should quickly point to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that Oracle try to parse your anonymous block, before to execute. If the sequence does not exist, than there will be error ORA-02289 on this line:

```
SELECT SEQ_GEN.NEXTVAL INTO V_NUM FROM DUAL;
```

and you cannot catch it, because happens on parse. You should get nextval dynamicly. If the sequence exists, there will be error on this line:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN';
```

but this error will be caught in WHEN OTHERS. Another thing is that you can use direct ORA-08004 when the max value is reached.

```
DECLARE
   sequence_reached_max_value   EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (sequence_reached_max_value, -8004);
   sequence_exists              EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (sequence_exists, -955);
   V_NUM                        NUMBER := 0;
   V_QUERY                      VARCHAR2 (2000);
   CNT                          NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   V_QUERY := 'CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 10 MAXVALUE 200';

   BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN sequence_exists THEN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY;
   END;

   BEGIN
      FOR I IN 1 .. 21
      LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SEQ_GEN.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL' into V_NUM;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_NUM);
      END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN sequence_reached_max_value THEN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('sequence has reached maximum value');
   END;

   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO CNT
     FROM USER_SEQUENCES
    WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'SEQ_GEN';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (CNT);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE
   V_NUM     NUMBER := 0;
   V_QUERY   VARCHAR2 (2000);
   CNT       NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   V_QUERY :='CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 10 MAXVALUE 200';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY; 

   FOR I IN 1 .. 11
   LOOP      
      V_QUERY :='SELECT SEQ_GEN.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY INTO V_NUM;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_NUM);

      IF V_NUM >= 200
      THEN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN';

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('sequence has reached maximum value');
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO CNT
     FROM USER_SEQUENCES
    WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'SEQ_GEN';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (CNT);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
END;
/
```